# Посоветуйте актуальные книги , курсы по django на русском

Tags: django

Посоветуйте актуальные книги , курсы по django на русском

Comment: На русском книг немного, поэтому можно и загуглить.

Comment: [Вопросы которые тем не менее не стоит задавать: Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что поиск книг является оффтопиком на ru so.